# disable and override keyboard shortcuts event in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events

In my project i need to provide keyboard shortcuts.There are some cases where I need to override default IE8 keyboard shortcuts.But on applying following code both the IE action and my function are called.

```
evt.cancelBubble = true;
evt.returnValue=false;
```

I have command bar visible in the browser. 
I want to disable the default IE actions in command bar/favourite bar.

Answer (score 0):

jquery's keydown is the way to go : http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

for example :

```
$('#target').keydown(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
...
```

this way you ensure cross browser compatibility as well

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I have handled the things for both the browsers.The problem I am facing is that when shortcuts of command bar in IE is pressed, both the actions i.e. my function and command bar menubar visibility are performed.I don't want to open command bar menu.